# Dspace 5.5 API response 500 when using Python 3 requests in script, returns 200 when testing in browser and Python Console

Tags: python, api, python-3.x, python-requests, dspace

I am trying to send a get request to DSpace 5.5 API to check if an item with a given handle is present in DSpace.

When I tested it in browser, it worked fine (return code 200, I've got the data about the searched item).

Then I began testing sending request with Python 3 requests module in Python console. Again, DSpace API returned correct response code (200) and json data in the response.

So, I implemented tested function into my script and suddenly DSpace API started to return error code 500. In the DSpace log I came accross this error message:

```
org.dspace.rest.RestIndex @ REST Login Success for user: jakub.rihak@ruk.cuni.cz
2017-01-03 15:38:34,326 ERROR org.dspace.rest.Resource @ Something get wrong. Aborting context in finally statement.
2017-01-03 15:38:34,474 ERROR org.dspace.rest.Resource @ Something get wrong. Aborting context in finally statement.
```

2017-01-03 15:38:34,598 ERROR org.dspace.rest.Resource @ Something get wrong. Aborting context in finally statement.

According to DSpace documentation, the request should by like this:

```
GET /handle/{handle-prefix}/{handle-suffix}
```

It is pointing to handle API endpoint on our DSpace server, so whole request should be sent to `https://dspace.cuni.cz/rest/handle/123456789/937` (I think you can test it yourself).

In the browser I get following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <item>
  <expand>metadata</expand
  <expand>parentCollection</expand>
  <expand>parentCollectionList</expand>
  <expand>parentCommunityList</expand>
  <expand>bitstreams</expand>
  <expand>all</expand>
  <handle>123456789/937</handle>
  <id>1423</id>
  <name>Komparace vývoje české a slovenské pravicové politiky od roku 1989 do současnosti</name>
  <type>item</type>
  <archived>true</archived>
  <lastModified>2016-12-20 17:52:30.641</lastModified
  <withdrawn>false</withdrawn>
 </item>
```

When testing in Python console, my code looked like this:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import requests

def document_in_dspace(handle):
    url = 'https://dspace.cuni.cz/rest/handle/'
    r_url = urljoin(url, handle)
    print(r_url)
    r = requests.get(r_url)

    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        print(r.text)
        print(r.reason)
        return True
    else:
        print(r.reason)
        print(r.text)
        return False
```

After calling this function in Python Console with `document_in_dspace('123456789/937')`, response was this:

```
https://dspace.cuni.cz/rest/handle/123456789/937
{"id":1423,"name":"Komparace vývoje české a slovenské pravicové politiky od roku 1989 do současnosti","handle":"123456789/937","type":"item","link":"/rest/items/1423","expand":["metadata","parentCollection","parentCollectionList","parentCommunityList","bitstreams","all"],"lastModified":"2016-12-20 17:52:30.641","parentCollection":null,"parentCollectionList":null,"parentCommunityList":null,"bitstreams":null,"archived":"true","withdrawn":"false"}
OK
True
```

So I've decided to implement this function into my script (without any changes), but now DSpace API returns response code 500 when function is called.

Details on the implementation are bellow:

```
def get_workflow_process(document):
    if document.document_in_dspace(handle=document.handle) is True:
        return 'delete'
    else:
        return None

wf_process = get_workflow_process(document)
    log.msg("Document:", document.doc_id, "Workflow process:", wf_process)
```

And the output is:

```
2017-01-04 11:08:45+0100 [-] DSPACE API response code: 500
2017-01-04 11:08:45+0100 [-] Internal Server Error
2017-01-04 11:08:45+0100 [-] 
2017-01-04 11:08:45+0100 [-] False
2017-01-04 11:08:45+0100 [-] Document: 28243 Workflow process: None
```

Can you please provide me with any suggestions what might be causing it and how to solve this? I am quite surprised that this works in Python Console but not in actual script and it seems I can't figure out by myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The problem was probably with some trailing newline characters in the `handle` param of the `document_in_dspace` function. Updated function looks like this:

```
def document_in_dspace(handle):
    url = 'https://dspace.cuni.cz/rest/handle/' # TODO: Move to config

    hdl = handle.rstrip()
    prefix, suffix = str(hdl).split(sep='/')

    r_url = url + prefix + '/' + suffix
    log.msg("DSpace API request url is:", r_url)

    r = requests.get(r_url, timeout=1)

    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        log.msg("DSPACE API response code:", r.status_code)
        log.msg("Document with handle", handle, "found in DSpace!")
        log.msg("Document handle:", handle)
        log.msg("Request:\n", r.request.headers)
        log.msg("\n")
        log.msg(r.reason)
        return True
    else:
        log.msg("DSPACE API response code:", r.status_code)
        log.msg("Document with handle", handle, "not found in DSpace!")
        log.msg("Document handle:", handle)
        log.msg("Request:\n", r.request.headers)
        log.msg("\n")
        log.msg(r.reason)
        return False
```

Basically, what I did was to call `.rstrip()` on handle string to get rid of all unwanted trailing charactes, then I separated the `prefix` and `suffix` parts of the handle (just for the sake of being sure) and constructed request url (`r_url`) by joining all the parts together.

I will make the function prettier in the future, but at least this now works as intended.

Output is following:

```
2017-01-04 15:06:16+0100 [-] Checking if document with handle 123456789/937
 is in DSpace...
2017-01-04 15:06:16+0100 [-] DSpace API request url is: https://dspace.cuni.cz/rest/handle/123456789/937
2017-01-04 15:06:16+0100 [-] DSPACE API response code: 200
2017-01-04 15:06:16+0100 [-] Document with handle 123456789/937
 found in DSpace!
2017-01-04 15:06:16+0100 [-] Document handle: 123456789/937

2017-01-04 15:06:16+0100 [-] Request:
 {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.11.1', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept': '*/*'}
2017-01-04 15:06:16+0100 [-] 
2017-01-04 15:06:16+0100 [-] OK
```

Nevertheless, DSpace API seems to return response code 500 when item with given handle is not present in the repository, instead of response code 404.